# Limits as x tends to 0 (proof)

Tags: limits

I Need to prove by ε−δ definition that:

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} {2^x} = 1$

I think I can assume that |x|< $\frac {1} {2}$,

I don't know how to continue now.

Comment: You know that you need $\epsilon > 0$. Do you have any ideas for a $\delta$ such that $-\epsilon+1<2^x<\epsilon+1$?

Comment: Or, if you want to skip the $\epsilon$ method, you can use the fact that $2^x$ is a strictly increasing function. Since you know that for any $a\in \mathbb{R}, a\ne 0 \implies a^0 = 1$, you can deduct that the limit must be one.

Comment: It may help you to write $2^x = e^{\ln(2^x)} = e^{\ln(2)x}$, in case you know any special limits involving $e$.

Comment: @jophny Typically, $\delta$ will be in terms of $\epsilon$. $\delta = 1$ won't work because if $x = 0.5 < \delta$, then $2^x = \sqrt{2}$, which is bigger than $\epsilon + 1$ for $\epsilon = 0.1$, for instance.

Comment: @jophny Notice that you need $|2^x-1|\lt\epsilon$ as the consequent of the definition of limit. This is equivalent to $-\epsilon\lt2^x-1\lt\epsilon,$ which is equivalent to $1-\epsilon\lt2^x\lt1+\epsilon.$ Furthermore, notice that this implies $x\lt\log_2(1+\epsilon).$ So in terms of $\epsilon,$ what is $\delta$?

Comment: @angel min{log2(1+ε),−log2(1−ε)} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Define $\delta:=\min\{\log_2(1+\varepsilon),-\log_2(1-\varepsilon)\}$.
Then $$|2^x-1|\le \max\{(2^{0+\delta}-1),(1-2^{0-\delta})\}\le \varepsilon$$
for every $x$ satisfying $|x-0|\le \delta$.